# 2nd level cache miss with referenced collection of composite-keyed entities

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate

I have an entity with a composite id `class_tier_info_id`, `item_type_id`, `stage`:

```
public class ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade : IEquatable<ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade>
{
    public virtual ClassTierInfo ClassTier { get; set; } // key-part

    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; } // key-part

    public virtual int Stage { get; set; } // key-part

    public virtual int Value { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Equals(ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Equals(ClassTier, other.ClassTier) && Equals(ItemType, other.ItemType) && Stage == other.Stage;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) // ...
    public override int GetHashCode() // ...
}


mapping.CompositeId()
    .KeyReference(x => x.ItemType, DbNamingHelper.FormatColumnName(nameof(ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade.ItemType)) + "_id")
    .KeyReference(x => x.ClassTier, DbNamingHelper.FormatColumnName(nameof(ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade.ClassTier)) + "_id")
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Stage);

// Value is auto-mapped

mapping.Schema("public");
mapping.Cache.Region("Static");
mapping.Cache.ReadOnly();
mapping.ReadOnly();
```

This entity is referenced from another entity `ItemType` (auto-mapped, same cache region):

```
public class ItemType
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade> TierUpgrades { get; set; }
        = new HashedSet<ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade>();
    // ...other properties...
}
```

All `ItemType` and `ClassTierItemTypeUpgrade` entities are preloaded and should be placed in the 2nd level cache.

But when loading other entities which reference `ItemType` I see in query log this:

```
SELECT tierupgrad0_.item_type_id  as item1_1_,
       tierupgrad0_.class_tier_id as class2_1_,
       tierupgrad0_.Stage         as Stage1_,
       tierupgrad0_.item_type_id  as item1_21_0_,
       tierupgrad0_.class_tier_id as class2_21_0_,
       tierupgrad0_.Stage         as Stage21_0_,
       tierupgrad0_.value          as value21_0_
FROM   public.class_tier_item_type_upgrade_infos tierupgrad0_
WHERE  tierupgrad0_.item_type_id = 5 /* :p0 */
```

which means that 2nd level cache is not used correctly.

But `ItemType` entity itself is actually loaded from 2nd level cache.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection cache settings should be specified separately from table (per collection):

```
// instance is ICollectionInstance
instance.Cache.Region("Region");
instance.Cache.ReadOnly();
```

But then I had [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246210/adding-2nd-level-collection-caching-raises-selects-count-from-150-to-3000) so now I'm not using it.